# Infinispan marshalling error for Hibernate entity with composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, infinispan, hibernate-4.x

I've switched my Hibernate cache from EHCache to Infinispan and I am now encountering an exception when modifying an entity with a composite primary key.  The entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Company_Message_Type")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class CompanyMessageType implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId private final CompanyMessageTypeId id = new CompanyMessageTypeId();

    @Column(name="FL_EXTERNAL_ACCESS", nullable=false)
    private boolean externalAccess;

    @Column(name="FL_VIEW_CONTENT", nullable=false)
    private boolean viewContent;

    @MapsId("companyId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_COMPANY", nullable=false)
    private Company company;

    @MapsId("messageTypeId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_MESSAGE_TYPE", nullable=false)
    private MessageType messageType;
}
```

The embedded Id class is as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompanyMessageTypeId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="ID_COMPANY", nullable=false)
    private Long companyId;

    @Column(name="ID_MESSAGE_TYPE", nullable=false)
    private Long messageTypeId;
}
```

Both classes have sensible `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

The exception only occurs when there is more than one server in the cluster.  The exception appears on the server(s) that are being updated.  The stack trace is as follows:

```
ISPN000220: Problems un-marshalling remote command from byte buffer
java.io.InvalidObjectException: Could not find a SessionFactory [uuid=0d0cdf26-dfe6-4285-9725-dfaa4821ecba,name=null]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateSessionFactoryOnDeserialization(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1781)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.readResolve(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1761)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadResolve(SerializableClass.java:413)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1270)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1711)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1627)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1269)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1711)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1627)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1591)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1269)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1711)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1627)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1269)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readParameters(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:100)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:30)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable$ExternalizerAdapter.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:389)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:205)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.JBossMarshaller$ExternalizerTableProxy.readObject(JBossMarshaller.java:152)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:351)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readParameters(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:100)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.readObject(CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.java:146)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.readObject(CacheRpcCommandExternalizer.java:59)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable$ExternalizerAdapter.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:389)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:205)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.JBossMarshaller$ExternalizerTableProxy.readObject(JBossMarshaller.java:152)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:351)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller.objectFromObjectStream(AbstractJBossMarshaller.java:136)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.VersionAwareMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:101)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.java:80)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.MarshallerAdapter.objectFromBuffer(MarshallerAdapter.java:28)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.handle(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:206)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.handleRequest(RequestCorrelator.java:460)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receiveMessage(RequestCorrelator.java:377)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receive(RequestCorrelator.java:247)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher$ProtocolAdapter.up(MessageDispatcher.java:665)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:708)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1015)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.RSVP.up(RSVP.java:187)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:165)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:381)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:370)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.tom.TOA.up(TOA.java:121)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:1010)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:234)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.AUTH.up(AUTH.java:118)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:694)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:381)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:600)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:147)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD.up(FD.java:255)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:301)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2.up(MERGE2.java:209)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:379)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MPING.up(MPING.java:181)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1399)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$MyHandler.run(TP.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in object of type org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl
    in field factory
    in object of type org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory$TypeScopeImpl
    in field typeScope
    in object of type org.hibernate.type.EmbeddedComponentType
    in field type
    in object of type org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheKey
```

Has anyone seen this error before?  It seems like infinispan might not be serializing the embedded id class correctly.

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5 and Infinispan 6.0.2

**EDIT:**

The problem is that Infinispan is sending a serialized version of the `CacheKey` over the network.  This key indirectly references the `SessionFactoryImpl` on the initiating machine, but the remote machine can't deserialize the `SessionFactoryImpl` and so throws this exception.  I believe that the problem is specific to entities with composite primary because if the key is just a `Long`, the `type` of the `CacheKey` would be something else that doesn't indirectly reference the `SessionFactoryImpl`.

In summary, I'm not sure if it's an Infinispan problem or a Hibernate problem.

Comment: I ended up reporting this as a bug: [HHH-9424](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9424)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the bug report.

Comment: Nathan, this looks really odd. I'm not sure the PR is valid. Would it be possible for you to share a zip or environment where I can run a test that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Also, is Hibernate running standalone or is it running within an application server?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm not sure the PR is valid"?  Hibernate is running within a web app on Tomcat.  I wrote a unit test that reproduces the issue - see the pull request for HHH-9424: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/820

Comment: The pull request is supposed to demonstrate the problem, not really propose an optimal fix.  The `typeScope` field on `ComponentType` is the problem because it isn't truly serializable.  The `typeScope` field isn't actually used in the class, so another possible fix would be to remove the field.  However, that doesn't solve the `@ManyToOne` issue also discussed on the pull request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed on the [pull request](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/820), apparently the `SessionFactory` is serializable across JVMs as long as it is named (see [HHH-6822](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6822)).  To fix my problem, I just needed to set the following Hibernate properties on the session factory:

```
hibernate.session_factory_name = MySessionFactory
hibernate.session_factory_name_is_jndi = false
```

Comment: 5,5 years have passed and I've just encountered the very same problem using the newest versions of hibernate and infinispan. The solution still works as well!